# Easier way to reset a nested dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a nested `dataclass` object and sometimes I have to reset the object with its default values. I thought re-creating it's object will do it. But it turn's out it's not changing values of it's nested class. 
Consider this example

```
In [16]: @dataclass
    ...: class Address:
    ...:     postal: str = "457009"
    ...:     address: str = "MG Road"

In [17]: @dataclass
    ...: class Details:
    ...:     name: str = "Mr. X"
    ...:     address = Address()
# I have two classes Address and Details with it's default value
In [18]: detail = Details()

In [20]: detail.address
Out[20]: Address(postal='457009', address='MG Road') # See it has default value

In [21]: detail.address.postal="000000" # Updating default value

In [22]: detail.address # Value is updated and can be seen
Out[22]: Address(postal='000000', address='MG Road')

In [23]: detail = Details()# My attempt to reset dataclass

In [25]: detail.address # As you can see value is not updated to default value
Out[25]: Address(postal='000000', address='MG Road')
```

My expectation is after updating it's value should be

```
Address(postal='457009', address='MG Road')
```

I saw the reference/hash value and it's not updated. Direct attributes are updated like if we'll update name this change will be reflected. 
Is there any way to do it quickly and in a better way then writing a complex `reset` method. As structure is very nested and it's quit time-consuming.

I am using `python 3.6.9`. Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: Do you need to be able to change the default value during the program? otherwise you can simply specify a default factory in Details: address: Address = field(default_factory=Address)

Comment: Thanks @stackToTheMoon !!! this is exactly what I am looking for.